# How to have a function as a member in a struct

Tags: struct, rust

How can I specify a function in a struct definition? Something like this:

```rust
struct Operation {
    params: Vec<String>,
    ops: Function<Vec<String>> -> Vec<String>,
}
```

I know that the syntax `Function<Vec<String>> -> Vec<String>` is incorrect, but I am trying to specify that "Operation" has a field called `ops` that is a closure that takes a `Vec<String>` and returns a `Vec<String>`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Box<dyn Fn(ArgType) -> RetType>` to store an arbitrary function:

```
struct Operation {
    params: Vec<String>,
    ops: Box<dyn Fn(Vec<String>) -> Vec<String>>,
}
```

In general, the [`Fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/ops/trait.Fn.html) trait (along with [`FnOnce`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html) and [`FnMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html)) can be used for any callable value, such as a function or a closure, that has the given function signature.

To create a `Box<dyn Fn...>` value, wrap any callable value with `Box::new`:

```
let obj = Operation {
    params: Vec::new(),
    // wrap a closure
    ops: Box::new(|strings| {
        /* do something... */
        strings
    }),
};

// call the function or closure inside the Box
(obj.ops)(Vec::new())
```

Comment: Note: `(obj.ops)(Vec::new())` require rust 1.35 stable